# WP Ubuntu/Mac image conversion differences

Tags: mac

On my local Mac when i upload a image it gets converted into a 300x300 thumbnail which looks good

When i upload the same image on my ubuntu based production server the quality is worse than my local mac and the image file size is larger.

Does anyone have an idea why that is?

The theme used is EXACTLY the same.
Plugins are the same.
Wordpress is the latest on both machines: 4.3.1.

i have attached both images to show the difference:

## From mac

[from mac http://artcast.dk/cassandra-300x300-local.jpg](http://artcast.dk/cassandra-300x300-local.jpg)

## From ubuntu server

[from server http://artcast.dk/cassandra-300x300-from-server.jpg](http://artcast.dk/cassandra-300x300-from-server.jpg)

Comment: I assume, probably either different settings for the image processing library or different libraries in use, e.g. ImageMagick on local and GD on production.

Comment: @ialocin as an answer please :) I can't think of anything else that would cause it either

Comment: the production had imagemagick module installed - removed and voila - now it makes a better compression and the file size is half the size! - thanks for leading me on the right path!

Comment: @Rarst ok, done :)

Comment: @MikkelLindhard My pleasure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, probably either different settings for the image processing library or different libraries in use, e.g. ImageMagick on local and GD on production.